# Live Agent chat persistence while user navigates through the website

Tags: liveagent, chat

Live agent is integrated in my project on the bottom of the screen. When I click "Start chat" button, it loads an iframe with the chat content within it:

[image: live agent persist chat][image]

The problem is: When I navigate through the website, the iframe closes, and when the user clicks "Start Chat" again, it just loads up the form.

I wanted to persist the chat connection while the user navigates, using cookies or something, is it possible to do that?

Comment: I think we'll need to see some code in order to help. Did you check the console for any error messages?

Comment: Nope, no error messages. It just "closes" the connection as if the user navigated away from the page.